# Does visualization form intuitions, or do intuitions lead to visualization?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry, process

When I get an idea from something, it feels like sometimes an abstract, inexplicable intuition leads to a concrete visualization (and a chain of logic), and sometimes it's the visualization and the logic that leads to the intuition.

**So, does visualization form intuitions, or do intuitions lead to visualization, and which is better?**

It seems to me this is related to "tenor and vehicle."  I'm thinking here of poetry, but not only of poetry.

> Tenor and vehicle [are] the components of a metaphor, with the tenor referring to the concept, object, or person meant, and the vehicle being the image that carries the weight of the comparison.
>
> https://www.britannica.com/art/tenor-literature

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate and perhaps provide some examples for clarity?

Comment: @GGx I just hope my flimsy description won't make my question and me look pedantic, I will try. I don't know if you have an experience(I think not only me but many people already has) that sometimes you use your intuition(I think intuition is very often-used term, but personally I think there is something more than two kinds of classificaion that intuition and logic, so I called it motive, sorry for abuse of terminology.), or sometimes you use logic or visualization to solve something.

Comment: I have such an experience and I wanted to get some opinion from someone who has similar experience to mine on here.

Comment: The original question was very hard to follow --perhaps English is a second language for you?  --so I edited it following the explanation you provided in your comments.  However, I'm still not entirely sure how this is a writing question (as opposed to a psychological or philosophical question).

Comment: I thought what I experienced is somewhat similar to the concept of tenor and vehicle. but I think I wrote an article on the wrong subsite. sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing is  and better suited for Psychology.SE

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about you, *the writer*, using intuitive language to help *your reader* form concrete visualizations and/or using concrete, visual and logical language to help the reader apprehend intuitive concepts?  I could see *that* being an on-topic writing question, and an interesting one, although it is probably broad enough that it should really be at least two separate questions.  On the other hand, if you are only talking about your own experience --even in response to others' writing --, it isn't a writing question (although it might be a literature question).

Comment: @ChrisSunami What I meant was not about the writer and the reader, thank you for your editing but the edited question is not quite expressing what I experienced(maybe because my question was too vague), because my experience is not about visual imagery or visualization(but I think Amadeus quite sufficiently answered to my question. Thank you Amadeus.)

Comment: I think everyone experiences the phenomenon that when they are listening to interesting story or idea, the brain automatically visualize the story or idea to not only understand easily but also memorize efficiently(I think the brain is very smart the brain know how to process information efficiently, although maybe someone will think this kind of personification is not "scientific".(but at least It is emperic to me))

Comment: or to the poet(but not only the poet. and I don't know much about poetry), sometimes they get visual imagery from "serendipity" or sometimes they get "serendipity" from visual imagery, or they use aural imagery to modify an phrases or an lines or style to make their work better. I knew these kinds of experiences

Comment: but what I meant was actually, for example, simple math problem that I solved "What is the greatest common divisor of two natural number if their sum is 19"
so a+b=19 is the question, as you can see in this question, there is nothing to visulize and nothing to observe that much. Let G is the greatest common divisor. then a+b=19 can be expressed as
G(x+y)=19 but 19 is a prime number so there is no G except when G=1.

Comment: I also can explain this by using words, that "If there are two natural number that has common divisor, then it can be expressed as multification of two natural numbers or multification of at least than two natural numbers and if the multiplicand or the multiplier is greater than or eqaul to 3 than each can be expressed as the sum of two natural number, but 19 is a prime number which means It's factors are 1 and itself so 19 can be expressed as a multification of two natural numbers 1 and 19,

Comment: and 19 can be expressed as the sum of two natural numbers a,b so the common divisor of a and b is 1 and it's the greatest common divisor"

Comment: but this kind of explanation is nothing but annotation,commentary. I already felt it before I explain it by words and before I notate It by symbols. I felt like there is motive(or the Idea that plato said) (and I felt the idea by the "intuition" but the idea is not the intuition.) but sometimes I think logic leads the Idea. also certain figures are needed to understand elementary geometry for example pythagorean theorem(I think in this case, certain figures are still not the idea. but very close.)

Comment: That's all I experienced, and I think I have to stop here.(because most importantly I think I wrote my article on the wrong subsite and I have no intention of making my experiences sounds like long and diffuse pseudophilosophy to others) Thank you all, and I'm particularly grateful to Amadeus. Thank you Amadeus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, does visualization form intuitions, or do intuitions lead to visualization, and which is better?

#### Yes!

From my study of biologically informed AI and neurology, I actually think the answer is both. Obviously what follows is my opinion on unsettled science of the brain; I will skip the IMO and state how I see it.

Clusters of neurons "model" or simulate something; meaning given some inputs, they process those and send signals to other clusters (their output is input to another cluster). They "recognize" a pattern in their inputs, and signal that recognition elsewhere; either higher or lower. A high level cluster can recognize that some object is a dog, or car, or tree. A very low level cluster can recognize a "line" and a slightly higher one can recognize it is horizontal, or vertical, or diagonal (btw those are real proven neural mechanisms in the visual cortex).

Even higher level clusters recognize words, physics, facial expressions (some people are damaged in this area), and predict "the future" in the sense of what is about to happen in the next few seconds.

We do not think in either words or images; we "think" in neural impulses traveling to neural clusters. When words appear in your mind, that is in the ***wake*** of a thought, the thought was a signal, the neural clusters in your head that ***recognize*** such a signal as being associated with a word will fire, and you feel exactly the same sensation as what happens when that word has been **spoken.** That's why it sounds in your head like speech, but the thought that triggered that speech is long gone.

The same thing is true for "seeing" things in your imagination. Actual sights (say a mountain) trigger corresponding neural clusters that model that object (hey I see a mountain), and then that cluster has links it is going to send to ten thousand other clusters informing them of a mountain in the field of vision. They too will fire, and some of them are linked to feelings about mountains (idiosyncratic to the person).  But that same cluster, because it links all things about "Mountain", also links to the word (in your language) "mountain", so hearing that word (or reading it then the cluster that recognizes it triggers the internal "hearing" of "mountain") will trigger your "everything about mountains" cluster, and can evoke the same feelings as if you saw a **generic** mountain. It is just a general model, of course, if you see Mount Fuji or Everest, there are more specific memories or facts involved. If the mountain is described, even if it is fictional, you can build up a more specific model of it: It is high, steep, and the west side has great ski slopes; the peak is often shrouded in cloud, it is craggy and the east slope is a favorite of expert rock climbers.

Now if I tell you this mountain has wheels, your brain will cast around for things that have wheels that could work with a mountain. Aha! (inspiration) It is a large prop in a school play, and it gets wheeled out on stage for certain scenes.

So both things can be true. Both intuitions and images are "models" of how things work. New intuitions can suggest images of things that "work" very similarly. The benzene molecule is a ring, August Kekulé's (a chemist) [had a dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Kekul%C3%A9#Kekul%C3%A9%27s_dream) that led to proving this was the structure of benzene; about a snake swallowing it's tail.

So one model (a snake forming a circle) can trigger a realization (intuition) that something else is similar. Or the subconscious realization (intuition) that benzene can ***only*** form a ring can trigger a model with a "ring" component; he might have thought of a wedding ring, a bicycle tire, a gear with six teeth, etc. For whatever reason in his brain, this snake image arose and helped to bring his subconscious realization into conscious thought. There is nothing about the benzene molecule that is a metaphorical "eating", but whatever works for you, Kekulé!

When trying to solve a problem, coming across an image (or anything) that has a component useful for solving the problem might trigger an intuition; Aha, I know how this works! Similarly, working through a problem and realizing a new model of how it most likely works can bring forth an image of something that shares many other characteristics.

That is how the mind works, this vast free for all of billions of neurons sending signals to each other all the time; not in words or images but signals. The words/sounds and images follow in the wake of thoughts, and can trigger other thoughts, but they are NOT "thoughts".

#### Which is better?

Probably intuition leads to an image, but either way has its drawbacks. Images are often metaphorical, and metaphors break down quickly; they don't go far in explaining something new. But if the explanation (insight) is what leads to the image, then you aren't relying on the image to tell you how it works. You **know** how it works, and the image is an aid in explanation, it doesn't bear the burden of **being** the explanation.

Comment: I really appreciate your sincere answer. It was really helpful. Thank you very much! I appreciate your consideration that you answered my question Neuro-scientifically. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is really about cognitive styles - and not (at least directly) about writing.

People have very different dominant cognitive styles. Sometimes different or multiple styles come into play. There's a whole field of creative problem solving which helps people break out of their dominant style/first approach to see things from multiple perspectives. See [this](http://www.creativeeducationfoundation.org) as a starting point (their big conference is in my city).

The best style is the one (or combination) that helps you understand or solve the issue at hand without limiting your field of choices so quickly that better possible solutions are never considered.

A shaman might approach a problem from an entirely different perspective than a physicist would. The results are what count.

And, as alluded to in another answer, a whole lot of scientific breakthroughs have occurred after someone used conventional methods to study a problem extensively, got stuck, and then took a nap and had a dream which put it all together for them. That's the physicist and the shaman working together in the same person.